# Искажение изображения при импорте в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Я сделал pixel art спрайт.При експорте .png файла на компьютер все было нормально.Но при импорте в Unity 2018 изображение стало битым

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш вопрос в дальнейшем будет полезен? Подсказка: обратите внимание на его рейтинг. Советую удалить его, так как в дальнейшем он, согласитесь, вряд ли принесет обществу пользу, а вам - баллы репутации

Answer (score -2):

Нашел решение здесь:
https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2275407.html
Нужно поставить Compression на None.